# pass relevant hidden field values from the form to the controller

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Im having a page that shows monthly subscriptions of a user which is created using codeigniter. what i want to do is when a the user clicks on make payment pass the values in the hidden files to the controller.

```
<?php echo form_open('options/done');?>
    <table class="tables">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Ref Code</th>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>action/th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($payments as $s =>$payment):?>
                <?php $month = $payment['month'];?>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $month;?>" name="month_<?php echo $s;?>" />
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $payment['ref_code'];?>" name="ref_<?php echo $s;?>" />
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $payment['ref_code'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $month;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $payment['year'];?></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="MAKE PAYMENT" class="red" /></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

so when someone hits the submit button how can i pass only the hidden values which are relevant to that table row?

Comment: move your form tags into the foreach loop and incremenet the form id names as well?

Comment: @Dave can i use the form tag inside the table?

Answer (score 2):

add form just inside the `<tr>` elements inside your loop  (see below with your code)

```
<?php foreach ($payments as $s =>$payment):?> 
<?php $month = $payment['month']; 
?> 
    <tr> 
        <form action="target.php" method="post" name="formName_<?php echo $s;?>" >
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $month;?>" name="month_<?php echo $s;?>" /> 
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $payment['ref_code'];?>" name="ref_<?php echo $s;?>" /> 
        <td><?php echo $payment['ref_code'];?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $month;?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $payment['year'];?></td> 
    <td><input type="submit" value="MAKE PAYMENT" class="red" /></td> 
        </form>
    </tr> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: note: assumes the rest of your code works, I just added the form tags in the right place.  just insure you increment the form names and you can have multiple on each page.

Comment: Actually, the placement of the opening form tag should come before the inputs, otherwise, they won't be in that form group.

He can place the inputs just after the opening form tag, or take the opening form tag and place it right after the 2nd php closing tag ?>

Comment: @Dave thanks for the guide. but when i submit no values are passed because i haven't given a name for the submit button and it works now. i have to write 12 if conditions to check which button has been clicked. Is there any other easy way to check which form/button has been submitted?